# reshape an irregular list in python

Tags: python, list

I would like to reshape the following list :

```
wide_list = [[1,['a','b','c']],[2,['d','e']],[3,'f']]
```

in a "long format":

```
long_list = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[1,'c'],[2,'d'],[2,'e'],[3,'f']]
```

How can this be achieved efficiently in Python?

Comment: Can you rewrite `wide_list` as a valid Python list? You're missing a closing bracket and I don't want to assume it goes around the final `'f'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> wide_list = [[1,['a','b','c']],[2,['d','e']],[3, ['f']]]
>>> long_list = [[k, v] for k, sublist in wide_list for v in sublist]
>>> long_list
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [2, 'e'], [3, 'f']]
```

Note, the last group had to be changed to match the pattern of the first two groups.  Instead of `[3, 'f']`, use `[3, ['f']]` instead.  Otherwise, you'll need special case logic for groups that don't follow the pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am a newbie to Pytho, can I ask a clarification? I understand that there is a nested loop here, but the syntax is not very clear. Does the "k, sublist" mean first and second element in each row of wide_list and then "for v in sublist" is looping in the elements of sublist, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is a correct interpretation.  See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

One way this can be done is  using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[x[0],letter] for x in wide_list for letter in x[1]]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [2, 'e'], [3, 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
long_list = [[x[0],item] for x in wide_list for item in x[1]]
```

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882997/reshape-an-irregular-list-in-python/7883038#7883038) is probably the most clear.

Comment: -1 because your answer doesn't handle the final list in his (hopefully fixed by now) definition of `wide_list`, then +1 to undo it because I realize he mis-specified the question.

Comment: @KirkStrauser No problem, I actually noticed and went to edit, then realized it was the spec, not my code as well.  Either way, Raymond's answer is best, IMO.